# Python subtract json objects from one json file if they occur in another json file

Tags: python, json

I'd like to be able to remove objects from one json file if they contain a key:value pair that matches another json file.

File1:

```
[
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "111",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example1"
  },
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "222",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example2"
  },
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "333",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example3"
  },
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "444",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example4"
  },
]
```

File2:

```
[
 [
  {
   "vmName": "example1"
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "vmName": "example2"
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "vmName": "example3"
  }
 ],
]
```

Desired result in file3(or modified file1):

```
[
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "444",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example4"
  },
]
```

I have found a few ways to remove elements from my first file, but I want to remove the entire object based on if it's k:v matches the any k:v in file2, I'm unaware of any way to do that.

Comment: Hi Fancy, does it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
def return_non_repetitive_records(file1, file2):
    result = file1.copy()
    for i in range(len(file2)):
        for j in range(len(result)):
            if result[j]['vmName'] == file2[i][0]['vmName']:
                result.pop(j)
                break
    return result
```

Usage:

```
file3 = return_non_repetitive_records(file1, file2)
```

Result:

```
[{'Admin': 'aaa',
  'id': '444',
  'osType': 'Windows',
  'publicIps': [],
  'resourceGroup': 'bbb',
  'vmName': 'example4'}]
```

The Data You Provided:

```
file1 = [
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "111",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example1"
  },
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "222",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example2"
  },
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "333",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example3"
  },
  {
    "Admin": "aaa",
    "id": "444",
    "osType": "Windows",
    "publicIps": [],
    "resourceGroup": "bbb",
    "vmName": "example4"
  },
]


file2 = [
 [
  {
   "vmName": "example1"
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "vmName": "example2"
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "vmName": "example3"
  }
 ],
]
```

Comment: Wow this worked exactly as intended. I had been looking for a json function or diff function that would perform this, but I hadn't even considered your approach. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to here that. Fancy, if it worked as just you expected, could you please consider to green tick my answer as the accepted answer?